# Send EAPoL packet: Request Identity

Tags: go, gopacket

I try to send Request Identity EAPoL packet:

```golang
func eapol_requestIdentity(handle *pcap.Handle, iface *net.Interface, id uint8) error {
    
        len := uint16(5) // eap1 field length
    
        eap1 := layers.EAP{
            Code: layers.EAPCodeResponse,
            Id:   id,
            Type: layers.EAPTypeIdentity,
            TypeData: []byte{byte(layers.EAPTypeIdentity)}, // bugfix
            Length:   len,
        }
    
        eapol := layers.EAPOL{
            Version: 1,
            Type:    layers.EAPOLTypeEAP,
            Length:  eap1.Length,
        }
    
        eth := layers.Ethernet{
            SrcMAC:       iface.HardwareAddr,
            DstMAC:       net.HardwareAddr{0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03},
            EthernetType: layers.EthernetTypeEAPOL,
        }
    
        buf := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
        opts := gopacket.SerializeOptions{
            //FixLengths:       true, // doesn't work
            FixLengths:       false,
            ComputeChecksums: true,
        }
    
        gopacket.SerializeLayers(buf, opts, &eth, &eapol, &eap1)
        log.Printf("send EOPoL : Request Identity %u...", id)
        if err := handle.WritePacketData(buf.Bytes()); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Send err ", err)
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("send packet [OK]")
    
        return nil
    }
```

I don't understand: if I delete line `TypeData: [] byte{byte(layers.EAPTypeIdentity)}` or line `Type: layers.EAPTypeIdentity`, my application sent a wrong packet.
Is it normal?... why must I set data twice for de same byte in packet?

Also, I tried to set FixLengths to true, but length fields are bads in sent packet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `EAP`, but according to the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3748#section-4.1), `Type` and `Type-Data` are two different fields:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     Code      |  Identifier   |            Length             |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     Type      |  Type-Data ...
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
```

So it stands to reason that if you leave out a piece of the packet, that it is "wrong".

As for the length, it seems there is a bug in gopacket when calculating the length. According to the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3748#page-23)

> The Length field is two octets and indicates the length of the EAP
> packet including the Code, Identifier, Length, Type, and Type-Data
> fields

But when `FixLengths` is `true`, [gopacket only counts `Type` and `Type-Data`](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/v1.1.19/layers/eap.go#L81).

```golang
if opts.FixLengths {
  e.Length = uint16(len(e.TypeData) + 1)
}
```

The `+1` should be `+5`, so it seems like you discovered a bug.

Edit: Looks like you already filled a bug report: https://github.com/google/gopacket/issues/931

Comment: Yes, I created this ticket. After I don't know enough about golang to fix second problem : auto EAPOL layer length calculation. 
EAPOL layer encapsulate EAP field(s) : I don't know max EAP fields number in a EAPoL packet. EAPOL layer length field value is the sum of EAP field lengths.